# How to unregister / cancel UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have some trouble finding this. Actually I want to unregister / cancel all of my local notification when I kill my appln from background. Any thoughts how can I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this to cancel all local notifications.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

And, of course, **you can't do this** when the app is killed from multi-tasking bar, since your app will not be notified by any means when it is killed from multi-tasking bar.

Comment: But my problem is where should I write this, when I kill my appln from multi-tasking bar which method get called. i placed an log in applicationWillTerminate, but its not getting called.

Comment: You do not get any kind of notification when your application gets killed for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is killed while in the background you do NOT get any notification and you do NOT get any chance to run or cleanup.  You must do this when you go into the background or wait until your app comes back to the foreground.

When an app is killed from the task bar while in the background it is sent a [SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) signal which cannot be caught by a signal handler, it is just summarily killed with no warning to the app.